# trying to get the cente lat/lon of a polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to populate a var "polyCenter" with the latlon for the center of a polygon and its driving me insane..

```
var paths = MapToolbar.features["shapeTab"]["shape_1"].getPath();
var i;

for (i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(paths[i]);
}
polyCenter = bounds.getCenter();
alert(polyCenter);
```

It keeps returning (0,-180) for some reason..

Comment: How does the bounds look like? What coordinates? I guess it could be screwed up if the shape goes round the poles or something.

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically an irregular polygon does not have a center.  They do however have a centroid (center of gravity) that is usually the approximate center.

Here is the equation to calculate the centroid of a polygon:

[image: centroid equation]

The equation in JavaScript:

```
function GetCentroid(paths){
    var f;
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var nPts = paths.length;
    var j = nPts-1;
    var area = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < nPts; j=i++) {   
        var pt1 = paths[i];
        var pt2 = paths[j];
        f = pt1.lat() * pt2.lng() - pt2.lat() * pt1.lng();
        x += (pt1.lat() + pt2.lat()) * f;
        y += (pt1.lng() + pt2.lng()) * f;

        area += pt1.lat() * pt2.lng();
        area -= pt1.lng() * pt2.lat();        
    }
    area /= 2;
    f = area * 6;
    return new google.maps.LatLng(x/f, y/f);
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/rQJj5/) based on @Argiropoulos answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/argiropoulostauros/cQLRr/) although this **is not the center** of a polygon except if it's a rectangle